# FCM push notification works after app Force Stop?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have used FCM to get push notifications, now if I Force stop the app from the settings on the Android device, will it be able to get push notifications?  I have read many posts that say in this case an app cannot receive notif.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *the many posts* say that it is not possible, then it's true.
If you have force stopped an app, it means you have abandoned it from doing any task by your wish and this also applies that the app will not be able to receive notifications.

Answer (score 0):

It heavily depends on which Android distro you're on. Especially which has their own "auto start manager"/"battery optimization level".

For example some MIUI version can receive FCM regardless of these settings, but some version can only do if the app's auto start is set to allowed.

On my Asus A12L phone, battery setting needs to not on restricted and Strong clean(basically force stop) is off and auto start is set to allowed. (There is actually no background process when you swipe it away in Recent tasks.) Most AOSP-like distros behave this way.